# Prevent / Avoid ^M in linux/unix script

Tags: shell, scripting

i have script like this below : `testing.sh`

```
#!/bin/bash

while read inputline
do
        plugin="$(echo $inputline | cut -d, -f 3-)"

        echo \"$plugin\" > test1.out
done < $1

exit 0
```

config file : `test.conf`

```
host1-192.168.31.200,Current_Users,check_users -w 20 -c 50
```

after execute the script :

```
#./testing.sh test.conf
```

the output file : `test1.out`

```
"check_users -w 20 -c 50^M"
```

How to prevent/avoid the `^M`?

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is probably to edit your test.conf file to remove it (did it come from another OS?).  However, you can also use tr to get rid of it:

```
plugin="$(echo $inputline | tr -d \\r | cut -d, -f 3-)"
```